# Mot pour lieu non découvert par l'homme

Tags: vocabulaire

Quel est le mot pour décrire un lieu qui n'a pas été découvert par l'homme ?

Je suis presque certain que c'est un mot très spécifique qui n'a pas d'autres sens que celui-ci.

Comment: Inexploré, peut-être ?

Comment: Non, par exemple la planète Mercure est inexploré mais découverte. Vierge n'est pas non plus le mot que je cherche. La définition de ce mot est vraiment spécifique à un lieu non découvert et à rien d'autre.

Comment: Si le lieu n'a pas été découvert, comment sait-on qu'il existe? a fortiori, pourquoi aurait-on besoin de qualifier cet endroit dont on ignore l'existence? Ou alors, à l'image de l'Atlantide connue seulement par d'anciens récits, on les dit _légendaires_.

Comment: @mouviciel J'ai eu la même pensée, mais évidemment on peut en parler comme on le fait maintenant. ;) Mais comme on n'en aura pas trop besoin, d'un tel terme, peut-être que ce que propose l'OP conviendrait déjà le mieux. « Terre non découverte ... »

Comment: Je pensais à des grottes non découvertes. On sait qu'il y a de grandes chances qu'il en reste beaucoup à découvrir, mais on ne les a pas découvertes. Du coup plutôt hypothétiques que légendaires.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On entend souvent parler de "*[Terra Incognita](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/terra_incognita/77432)*" qui vient du latin et signifie "terre inconnue". Sinon je pense à terre "*jamais [foulée](http://dictionnaire.reverso.net/francais-definition/fouler%20le%20sol%20%28d%27un%20pays%29)*".

Comment: Tu peux aussi citer un dictionnaire : [Territoire inconnu, inexploré](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/terra_incognita). Ou [une encyclopédie...](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terra_incognita). C'est toujours une référence plus tangible que "on entend". +1

Comment: C'est noté, j'ajoute les références à ma réponse.

Comment: Merci pour ta réponse, apparemment c'est ce mot. Wikipédia prétend que c'est encore utilisé pour les abysses et les cavernes, et c'est exactement le cas d'usage pour lequel j'en avais besoin.

Answer (score 2):

La réponse de Shashimee répond à la question qui est posée.

J'ajouterai juste que l'adjectif [vierge](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/vierge/81935/locution) pour parler d'une région (terre, forêt, etc) qualifie une zone, connue ou non, explorée ou non, mais laissée intacte par l'activité humaine intensive.